# Zip files size anomaly

Tags: java, file, zip, size

I am seeing something unusual in my zip files.
 I have two `.txt` files and both are then zipped through `java.util.zip(ZipOutputStream, ZipEntry ...)` in my application and then returned in response as downloadable zip files through the browser.
One file has data which is a database blob and other is a `StringBuffer`. My blob txt file is of size 10 mb and my `StringBuffer` txt file is 15 mb but when these are zipped the blob txt zip file has size larger that the `StringBuffer` txt file although it contains a smaller txt file.
Any reason why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

- the StringBuffer and (as of Java 5) StringBuilder classes store just
  the buffer for the character data plus current length (without the
  additional offset and hash code fields of a String), but that buffer
  could be larger than the actual number of characters placed in it;
- a Java char takes up two bytes, even if you're using them to store
  boring old ASCII values that would fit into a single byte;

Answer (score 0):

Your BLOB -- *binary* large object -- probably contains data that isn't text, and as compressible as text. For example, it could contain an image.

If you don't already know what the blob contains, you can use a hexdump program to look at it.

Comment: Thanks anon , but the blob doesn't contain any images or any data other that txt.

Comment: Facing a similar issue with 2 blobs which have small difference in size say 8 mb but the zip files of these two are having a difference of above 20 mb. Note that both these file are pipe separated text files.